# Append, Extend, Remove, Replace - Python Lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am trying to populate a list and iterate over it to replace if an item exists.
Each item in my list has 5 attributes i.e e1,e2,e3,e4 and e5. e1 is like my primary key based on which I want to perform replace and remove operations.Currently, I am searching for this key i.e

```
myList = [0,0,0,0,0] 
for i in myList:
    If (i[0] == key):
        i[1] = somevalue
        i[2] = somevalue
        i[3] = somevalue
        i[4] = somevalue
 # Perform some calculation here
        # Replace the i[1],i[2],i[3],i[4] values for this item. i[0] still stays same.
```

I am getting an error in the "if" condition: 'int' object not subscriptable. My initial list is empty. I need to populate values first and in the next iteration replace the values of only the 2,3,4 and 5th elements. The first element remains same. I would like to know where I am going wrong here and how do I do the replace for every item in the list based on the first element.

Comment: `i` there is 0 (the first element) and you're trying to subclass it like it's a list. It's an integer. Just use [list.index()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) to get the position of the first occurrence of a value in the list and then use that index to modify what's at that position as desired.

Comment: i is the item in your list in first loop i is 0 and then you say 0[0] == key?! myList should look like this [[0,0,0,0,0]]

Comment: @rebeling : Got it! The error is handled now. Can you suggest how I can replace only a part of the elements of an Item in the list based on the element in the first index?
I tried to remove the entire list and append it again with the new values, but i want to know if there is an efficient way..

Comment: @rebeling is the double bracket a python 3 thing?   in my interpreter it works fine with single bracket..

Comment: @tenwest It's a nested list -- two different things that works in any version of Python. It 'works' with single brackets by creating a single list. The double brackets creates a list whose members are themselves lists.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing your **myList** correctly. You want

```
myList = [[0,0,0,0,0]]
```